# How to add a Value to Model State while there is already a key for that? MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

Good Morning, Evening or night

I was wondering how I can add a value to an existing key in ModelState. Here is what I have done yet:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VM_RoleGroup vm_roleGroup)
    {
        RoleGroup roleGroups = Mapper.Map<VM_RoleGroup, MAHAL_E_MA_Model.POCO.RoleGroup>(vm_roleGroup);
        roleGroups.ModifiedDate = UtilityHands.GeneralTools.ConvertToShamsi(DateTime.Now);
        roleGroups.Description = vm_roleGroup.Description ?? MAHAL_E_MA_Proj.ApplicationResources.GeneralResource.NoDescription;

        **if (ModelState.ContainsKey("ModifiedDate") && ModelState["ModifiedDate"].Value == null)
        {
            ModelState["ModifiedDate"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", roleGroups.ModifiedDate, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);    
        }
        else if (!ModelState.ContainsKey("ModifiedDate"))
        {
            ModelState.Add("ModifiedDate", new ModelState { Value = new ValueProviderResult("", roleGroups.ModifiedDate, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) });
        }**

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitOfWork.RoleGroupRepository.InsertData(roleGroups);
            unitOfWork.RoleGroupRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(vm_roleGroup);
    }
```

But the ModelState is still invalid since it lacks the Value of a key named 'ModifiedDate'. Remember that, the value is not set on the client side by the user. It needs to be set programmatically. By the way, The 'ModifiedDate' is a **required** field in the database.

Any ideas pleas? Thanks in advance

Comment: does the viewmodel contain a field for ModifiedDate? why would it the modelstate be considered invalid if it doesn't contain the key?

Comment: @user1778606: Yes the ViewModel contains the property. Actually, the ModelState has the key but there is no value belong to it. In deed, I am not passing the ModifiedDate from the View to the Controller, since the User is not responsible for it. But now I think I need to do that and pass the Date as a HiddenField or something like that. Don't you think so?

Comment: I think that would be the easiest way to skirt the problem. Just overwrite the modified date when it gets back to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass the ModifiedDate through as part of the viewmodel, and then just overwrite it to DateTime.Today in the controller.

ie. prepopulate it the view

```
@Html.Hidden(Model.ModifiedDate,DateTime.Today);
```

and since this isn'tsecure, overwrite it in the controller

```
roleGroups.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today;
```

or if its a universal field across your entire application (on all models), you can actually add custom code to do this in the mapper, but I'm unsure of the circumstances.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea! I will try it out and come back with the result. Thank you..

Comment: I wrote exactly the the code you've suggested for the View. It results in an Error (related to 'Model.ModifiedDate'): 'The value cannot be null'. It is right since no data has been inserted yet so that empty values are all we have. Then, I omitted 'DateTime.Today' so it worked fine and displayed the 'Create' view. But as pressing the 'Save' button, as if no post was taken place. I have no idea why! Anyhow.. against my interest I decided to ignore the 'ModelState.IsValid' and wrote some custom validations :(

Comment: hmm, I duuno about that, using the model state is usually an effective way (less code and less maintainence). good luck